Does the police lying and causing a loss constitute fraud?
There is a Guardian Consumer story about someone given incorrect information by the police that resulted in a loss:

In March, they called me because a 90-year-old man I try to help was not answering his doorbell. The police had been called because he hadn’t turned up at his book group. They forced their way in and found the man safe in bed, as I had predicted they would.
The PC who was there then asked me to cover the costs of an emergency response team to make safe his front door. I was told I would be reimbursed and would be sent a claim form. Trying to be helpful, and having checked and double-checked with the constable that I would be reimbursed, I duly made a card payment to the emergency response team for £960.
Two months and many phone calls and letters later, and the Met is refusing to reimburse me. My claim has been repeatedly rejected because there was no negligence on behalf of the Met, which acted according to the law.

In the real world we do not know what happened, or what the PC believed.  Here we consider the hypothetical where this was on body cam footage, including an assurance by the PC that reimbursement was certain and a non-public comment showing the PC understood that reimbursement was unlikely because there was no negligence.
Fraud by false representation is defined as:

The defendant:

made a false representation
dishonestly
knowing that the representation was or might be untrue or misleading
with intent to make a gain for himself or another, to cause loss to another or to expose another to risk of loss.

The offence is entirely focused on the conduct of the defendant.

It would seem that the story as told would meet this definition.  Is this correct reading of the law?  Is there another clause that would protect the PC in this instance?

The story does not indicate the officer "lied" or was otherwise dishonest in the legal sense. A lie is a deliberate deceit.

@Lag I thought the paragraph starting with "In the real world" covered this point.  Does it need more clarification?

I see on re-reading what you mean but I think you could word it more simply. But then the answer seems to be obvious.


Does the police lying and causing a loss constitute fraud?

If the hypothetical circumstances include that the police officer lied to make a gain, cause a loss or expose another to loss then the answer is necessarily yes because, as written, the law covers any person and there is no exception for police officers in section 2 itself or elsewhere. A lie isn't fraud in itself.
This question's hypothetical circumstances and the real circumstances that inspired it are so specific and peculiar it seems unlikely there is any relevant case law or analogous or similar cases.
Some police officers have been charged with section 2 fraud and some of them have been found guilty of it. Fundamentally these cases involved them lying to make a benefit for themselves. There is no indication that this real officer is related to the "emergency response team" such that it would benefit her if they received money from people she persuaded to pay them. It just seems she honestly although wrongly believed something to be true and because of that she misled the complainant to believe it too - that's not fraud.

Section 2 Fraud by false representation, Fraud Act 2006:

(1) A person is in breach of this section if he—
(a) dishonestly makes a false representation, and
(b) intends, by making the representation—
(i) to make a gain for himself or another, or
(ii) to cause loss to another or to expose another to a risk of loss.
(2) A representation is false if—
(a) it is untrue or misleading, and
(b) the person making it knows that it is, or might be, untrue or
misleading.
(3) “Representation” means any representation as to fact or law,
including a representation as to the state of mind of—
(a) the person making the representation, or
(b) any other person.
(4) A representation may be express or implied.
(5) For the purposes of this section a representation may be regarded
as made if it (or anything implying it) is submitted in any form to
any system or device designed to receive, convey or respond to
communications (with or without human intervention).

For "dishonesty" the finder of fact must decide the state "of the individual's knowledge or belief as to the facts and then determine whether his conduct was honest or dishonest by the (objective) standards of ordinary decent people. There is no longer a requirement that the defendant must appreciate that what he has done is, by those standards, dishonest." (Crown Prosecution Service guidance - Fraud Act 2006)

What dishonesty?
Being wrong is not the same thing as being dishonest.


It would seem that the story as told would meet this definition. Is this correct reading of the law?

No, the situation in the story lacks 3 out of 4 fraud factors.
the crucial elements of fraud are:

made a false representation
dishonestly
knowing that the representation was or might be untrue or misleading
with intent to make a gain for himself or another, to cause loss to another or to expose another to risk of loss.

The story, as told lacks 3 of them: There's no indication of dishonesty, there is no sign of the PC knowing their statement to be wrong and nothing indicates an intent to defraud.
Without all four factors proveable - and camera footage of the exact exchange is at worst only proving the false representation - there is no fraud.
In case that the latter 3 points can not be proven, the finder of fact is required to vote non guilty and assume an honest error in estimating that there will be reimbursement. That isn't intent, dishonesty and knowingly and thus not fraud.
To make it fraud
To make it fraud, the police officer would have been required to:

be acting disonestly in the representation (from the wording of the representation)
be clearly on notice that the department would never reimburse a claim, to do the representation knowingly
have some sort of provable ill intent towards the victim

